# Call handler after multiple ajax requests have all returned

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous

What is an elegant way of calling a handler after several ajax requests have returned?

Situation: my web app performs a batch operation on a REST API by calling the API say 20 times using concurrent ajax requests. After each of the requests has returned, I would like to store the results and present a GUI to the user.

Is there an easy way to somehow group ajax request objects and call a handler when they are all done? The only way I can think of is defining a handler that checks if each of the calls has returned, and calling it each time any of the calls returned, but that is a bit of a mess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var requests = [];

requests.push($.ajax(...));
requests.push($.ajax(...));
requests.push($.ajax(...));

$.when.apply($, requests).done(function() {
    // all requests finished successfully
});
```

Something to read:

- http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/
- http://joseoncode.com/2011/09/26/a-walkthrough-jquery-deferred-and-promise/

Comment: Probably also helpful: http://learn.jquery.com/code-organization/deferreds/.